# Nesting Regular Expressions

Tags: regex, oracle

I am trying to nest a regular expression to fix the output that I'm getting from some data. I can not control the data, it's from a different source that I don't have write access to. I clean it up when I copy it over. The problem is a name, and again, yes, I know the problem is really the source, I can't change what they send.

I'm using Oracle SQL Developer, on an Oracle 11g database in case that matters.

Name: `Nancy (Alice)`

What I need: `Nancy Alice`

What I am getting: `Nancy  Alice`

There are two spaces between the names because the space that is there stays, **and the parenthesis turns into a space**.

There needs to be only one space between the names, and no space after them.

This works to remove the special characters

```
REGEXP_REPLACE(first_name, '[^0-9A-Za-z]', ' ')
```

Then I get `Nancy  Alice` , two spaces between the names, with a space after it.

This works to remove to remove the special characters and then trim the output

```
trim(REGEXP_REPLACE(first_name, '[^0-9A-Za-z]', ' '))
```

Then I get `Nancy  Alice`, two spaces between the names, but trailing space gone.

As I said, the problem is that I need to have only one space between the names.

I tried this to get rid of the special characters and then get rid of the double and trailing space:

```
REGEXP_REPLACE(REGEXP_REPLACE(first_name, '[^0-9A-Za-z]', ' '),'/^\s+|\s+$/g', '')
```

It didn't work, I still had the double

I tried this:

```
trim(REGEXP_REPLACE(REGEXP_REPLACE(first_name, '[^0-9A-Za-z]', ' '),'\\s+', ' '))
```

and

```
trim(REGEXP_REPLACE(REGEXP_REPLACE(first_name, '[^0-9A-Za-z]', ' '),'/\s\s+/g', ' '))
```

And a few other iterations of the second "replace two with one" expression, but nothing has been successful.

Trim seems to always work, as does the replace special characters, however, once that is done, I haven't been able to get rid of the double space that the first expression is creating.

I have been searching on the site, and none of the examples that I have found so far have worked.

What am I missing here?

Thanks!

Michelle

Comment: Add one or more quantifier (`+`) to the set of characters to remove: `[^0-9A-Za-z]+`

Comment: Change `' '` to either NULL or `''` in your expressions above and you're probably good to go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace multiple spaces with a single space after replacing special characters and trimming the surrounding spaces.

```
REGEXP_REPLACE(TRIM(REGEXP_REPLACE('[^0-9A-Za-z]', ' ')), '\s{2,}', ' ')
```

Comment: THAT DID IT!!!! I'll run it through the other matches and see if we're fully corrected.

Comment: I ran it against the other 3,000+ names, and it seems to have worked across the board. This name was my single problem child. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

> the parenthesis turns into a space
>
> [...]
>
> This works to remove the special characters:
>
> `REGEXP_REPLACE(first_name, '[^0-9A-Za-z]', ' ')`

The only reason that the parentheses turn into spaces is because you're explicitly replacing them with a space in the above operation.

If your plan is just to **delete** the special characters, you could instead replace them with an **empty string** instead of a space; thus potentially eliminating this whole problem of "trimming multiple spaces"?

```
REGEXP_REPLACE(first_name, '[^0-9A-Za-z ]', '')
```

---

I'm not entirely convinced that editing a "first name" of `Nancy (Alice)` to `Nancy Alice` is the "correct" solution, but I leave that judgement call to you.

Comment: I can't simply remove them and replace with nothing because I have other names with apostrophes and hyphens, which also need to be spaces.

O'Neil changes to O Neil
Smith-Jones to Smith Jones
Renee' to Renee

This has to cover more than 3,000 names that come in all sorts of ways

Comment: This name was my single problem child out of over 3,000. The rest worked correctly. By the way, I agree with you, this is not the "correct" solution, as the names are supposed to be their legal names, and I've never seen a name with parentheses in it.  However, what is entered into the HR system isn't up to me, I just receive the data after the fact. I get what I get and I have to deal with it.

Comment: @MichelleH *"I have other names with apostrophes and hyphens, which also need to be spaces"* -- Then what I would do is explicitly replace apostrophes and hyphens with spaces, and then replace all other special characters with an empty string. I think that would be the  most simple and explicit approach.

Comment: What I would do is leave correctly formatted names alone, and not enter names into a human resources system that are not legal names. But that's just me. lol In any case, it's now working. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes regular expressions are overkill. If your data is always formatted as shown above the following will do the work, perhaps more clearly:

```
REPLACE(REPLACE(first_name, '(', ''), ')', '')
```

On the other hand, you could use the following regular expression-based code:

```
FIRST_NAME := REGEXP_SUBSTR('Nancy (Alice)', '[^()]+', 1, 1) ||
              REGEXP_SUBSTR('Nancy (Alice)', '[^()]+', 1, 2);
```

[db<>fiddle here](https://dbfiddle.uk/rHITFJkU)

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to remove the `()` brackets from a string then you do not need regular expressions can use a single call to `TRANSLATE`:

```sql
TRANSLATE(first_name, 'A()', 'A')
```

If you want to get rid of all non alpha-numeric, non-space characters then:

```sql
REGEXP_REPLACE(first_name, '[^[:alnum:] ]')
```

Note: Don't provide a third argument and it will not insert the extra spaces.

---

For the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (first_name) AS
SELECT 'Nanny (Alice)' FROM DUAL;
```

Then:

```
SELECT first_name,
       TRANSLATE(first_name, 'A()', 'A') AS replacement1,
       REGEXP_REPLACE(first_name, '[^[:alnum:] ]') AS replacement2
FROM   table_name;
```

Outputs:

| FIRST_NAME | REPLACEMENT1 | REPLACEMENT2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Nanny (Alice) | Nanny Alice | Nanny Alice |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/KV-tJ4KB)